# Trying to add a linkkey to my bluetooth keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (dual boot system)

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, keyboard, bluetooth

So long story short I have a dual boot laptop and i've got a bluetooth keyboard (logitech k380)

I've followed  this tutorial [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255509/bluetooth-pairing-on-dual-boot-of-windows-linux-mint-ubuntu-stop-having-to-p) but on step 4.1 i get this message

```
sudo edit /var/lib/bluetooth/34\:F3\:AA\:AA\:AA\:AA/linkkeys
Error: no write permission for file "AA:AA:AA:AA/linkkeys' (No such file or directory)::/var/lib/bluetooth/34:F3:AA:AA:AA:AA/linkkeys"
```

so i've tried to do an ls on that path

```
$ sudo ls /var/lib/bluetooth/34:F3:AA:AA:AA:AA
```

ls: cannot open directory '/var/lib/bluetooth/34:F3:AA:AA:AA:AA': Permission denied

i want to add the same linkkey that i have on my windows machine to ubuntu the keyboard is paired on both OS but 1 of them won't recognize the device after a reboot.

Comment: 34:F3:9A:72:9A:AB i dont think this is a dir its the address of the Bluetooth device

Comment: it's the only mac address that appear in the  /var/lib/bluetooth path, Can you change the mac address please? thank you

Comment: a mac address of a device can not be changed

Comment: i meant in your first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04, worked-around it by using a Root Explorer instead

I used this command:
sudo nautilus

That way I could navigate to the bluetooth folder and change the linkkey!